# math stats with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of **person** objects (IEnumerable) and each person has an **age** property.

I want to generate stats on the collection such as Max, Min, Average, Median, etc on this age property.

What is the most elegant way of doing this using LINQ?

Comment: Be careful if the data is comming from a database, as Linq may read the data more then once, however in your case Linq should be a good tool as you seem to have your collection in ram.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
var max = persons.Max(p => p.age);
var min = persons.Min(p => p.age);
var average = persons.Average(p => p.age);
```

**Fix for median in case of even number of elements**

```
int count = persons.Count();
var orderedPersons = persons.OrderBy(p => p.age);
float median = orderedPersons.ElementAt(count/2).age + orderedPersons.ElementAt((count-1)/2).age;
median /= 2;
```

Comment: Little note here, that this algorithm is not time-optimal. Median can be calculated in O(n) time.

Comment: @Max Where is your time-optimal solution?

Comment: Note that this method may give wrong results if the list contains null values. One needs to filter out those null values before using it!

Answer (score 46):

Here is a complete, generic implementation of Median that properly handles empty collections and nullable types. It is LINQ-friendly in the style of Enumerable.Average,  for example:

```
    double? medianAge = people.Median(p => p.Age);
```

This implementation returns null when there are no non-null values in the collection, but if you don't like the nullable return type, you could easily change it to throw an exception instead.

```
public static double? Median<TColl, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TColl> source,
    Func<TColl, TValue>     selector)
{
    return source.Select<TColl, TValue>(selector).Median();
}

public static double? Median<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
        source = source.Where(x => x != null);

    int count = source.Count();
    if(count == 0)
        return null;

    source = source.OrderBy(n => n);

    int midpoint = count / 2;
    if(count % 2 == 0)
        return (Convert.ToDouble(source.ElementAt(midpoint - 1)) + Convert.ToDouble(source.ElementAt(midpoint))) / 2.0;
    else
        return Convert.ToDouble(source.ElementAt(midpoint));
}
```

Comment: This, AFAIK, enumerates the source 2 or 3 times: first when `Count()` is called, second (and possibly third time) - when ElementAt is called.

Comment: You're absolutely right. And -- as always with LINQ -- the impact of this will range from trivial to prohibitive, depending on the nature of your collection. Remember the Rules of Optimization:
Rule 1: Don't do it.
Rule 2 (for experts only): Don't do it yet. (See http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-arent-my-optimizations-optimizing/)

Answer (score 14):

Max, Min, Average are part of Linq:

```
int[] ints = new int[]{3,4,5};
Console.WriteLine(ints.Max());
Console.WriteLine(ints.Min());
Console.WriteLine(ints.Average());
```

Median is easy:

**UPDATE**

I have added order:

```
ints.OrderBy(x=>x).Skip(ints.Count()/2).First();
```

**BEWARE**

All these operations are done in a loop. For example, ints.Count() is a loop so if you already get ints.Length and stored to a variable or simply use it as it is, would be better.

Comment: `ints.ElementAt(ints.Count()/2)`

Comment: for the Median to be right you need to order the array first.

Comment: Your implementation of `Median` also assumes that the input has an odd number of elements. It will fail for `{0, 1}` (it will give 0 instead of 0.5).

Comment: @Mark - AFAIK Median will always return one of the source array elements

Comment: @Itay: No, that's usually called the medoid. *A related concept, in which the outcome is forced to correspond to a member of the sample is the medoid.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median The way you are calculating the medoid is biased as it will often return a value that is lower than the median, and never a value that is higher.

Answer (score 7):

### Get median using Linq (works for even or odd number of elements)

```
int count = persons.Count();

if (count % 2 == 0)
    var median = persons.Select(x => x.Age).OrderBy(x => x).Skip((count / 2) - 1).Take(2).Average();
else
    var median = persons.Select(x => x.Age).OrderBy(x => x).ElementAt(count / 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

My `Median` LINQ extension, using [Generic Math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) (.NET 7+)

```
public static TSource Median<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    where TSource : struct, INumber<TSource>
    => Median<TSource, TSource>(source);

public static TResult Median<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    where TSource : struct, INumber<TSource>
    where TResult : struct, INumber<TResult>
{
    var array = source.ToArray();
    var count = array.Length;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements.");
    }
    Array.Sort(array);
    var index = count / 2;
    var value = TResult.CreateChecked(array[index]);
    if (count % 2 == 1)
    {
        return value;
    }
    var sum = value + TResult.CreateChecked(array[index - 1]);
    return sum / TResult.CreateChecked(2);
}
```